# Namespace package __spec__.loader and __loader__ attributes not set to None

Tags: python, import, namespaces, package, python-import

The [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#path-entry-finder-protocol) states:

> To indicate to the import machinery that the spec represents a
>   namespace portion. the path entry finder sets “loader” on the spec to
>   `None` and “submodule_search_locations” to a list containing the
>   portion.

The [Python Library Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec.loader) states:

> The loader to use for loading. For namespace packages this should be
>   set to `None`.

Yet creating a namespace package whose portions are located in two different paths `a/` and `b/` on the file system:

```
a/
  namespace_package/
    module_1.py
    module_2.py
b/
  namespace_package/
    module_3.py
```

then adding these paths to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH="a:b"
```

and finally importing the namespace package and printing its `__spec__.loader` and `__loader__` attributes with the CPython 3.7 interpreter:

```
python3 -c "import namespace_package; print(namespace_package.__spec__.loader); print(namespace_package.__loader__)"
```

shows that they are *not* `None`:

> <_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x104b04128>
>   <_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x104b04128>

Is it a documentation error, an implementation error or my misinterpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [it was right](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b523f8433a8982e10eb41a3e2b37ee0e6d6a6e00) but [has been changed](https://bugs.python.org/issue32303).

Opened an issue to track it: https://bugs.python.org/issue35181

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it was once `None`, but is no longer, due to changes in Python. Is it causing you a problem? If so, then I would raise an issue, but the resolution might well be to have the documentation updated. Can you check what results you get with Python 3.6 and/or 3.5? Also might be worth checking the Python release notes to see what updates there have been in this area.

Comment: I checked on Python 3.3.0 (the version where [implicit namespace packages](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages) were introduced) and the `__loader__` attribute was *not* `None` from the beginning!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `mod.__spec__.loader` is not the same thing as `mod.__loader__`.  The spec's loader should still be `None`.  The module's loader is set by the import machinery to an instance of the internal `_NamespaceLoader`, partly for the sake of reloading.  Perhaps the docs aren't clear enough on this.

Comment: But this is not the case: both `__loader__` and `__spec__.loader` attributes are *not* `None` but the same `_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader` object. I have updated my question to reflect that. So I think we have a problem here.

Comment: This is because the implementation of PEP 420 was changed in February 2018 here: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/5481